# Error while trying to execute hdfs command

Tags: macos, hadoop, hdfs

While trying to copy a file from local disk to `hdfs` it shows error even though the syntax is proper. It says no such file or directory even though the file physically does exist.

What should I do? I have tried all the 3 commands to transfer/copy the file.

`hadoop fs -put /Users/Sneha/Desktop/bank.xlsx /user/gulafsha_parveen_simplilearn/myproject`

Shows Error:

> no such file for /Users/Sneha/Desktop/bank.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

I think one good way to troubleshoot will be to do an ls with the same user. Something like below.

```
>>$ ls /Users/Sneha/Desktop/bank.xlsx
```

Hope the output will make things clear.